# How to remove explore form from Top navbar in Swagger UI using docker-compose

Tags: docker, swagger, swagger-ui

How to remove explore form from Top navbar in Swagger UI using docker-compose?

[image]

Now it looks like:

```
version: "3"

volumes:
  mongodbdata:

services:

  swagger-ui:
    image: swaggerapi/swagger-ui
    container_name: swagger-ui
    depends_on:
      - generator-swagger-ui
    ports:
      - "8001:8080"
    expose:
      - "8001"
    volumes:
      - ./swagger:/usr/share/nginx/html/swagger
    environment:
        API_URL: swagger/swagger.json
        BASE_URL: /swagger-ui/
```

Answer (score 0):

You must genereate a custom image of **swaggerapi/swagger-ui** removing the **Topbar plugin** from `src/standalone/index.js`, like this:

```
 let preset = [
  // TopbarPlugin,
  ConfigsPlugin,
  () => {
    return {
      components: { StandaloneLayout }
    }
  }
]
```

Reference: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/212396f24d0d0f072d06c6af71087d6fddef9134/README.md#topbar-plugin