# Spring boot springdoc-openapi swagger UI how to hide the Explore section

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, swagger-ui

I'm build a Swagguer UI to expose some Rest API using Spring boot 3.0.2 et springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui 2.0.2 and maven

I would like to hide the **Explore** Section as highlighted on the following image. Is there any Springboot configuration to hide that section?

Thanks so much

[image]

Comment: Probably you can do this by customizing the CSS https://springdoc.org/#customizing-swagger-static-resources. Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68653453/how-to-remove-explore-form-from-top-navbar-in-swagger-ui-using-docker-compose

Comment: Thanks PeterMmm for your answer.

Finally, i have been able to hide the Explore Section by adding the following lines to my applicatio.properties file
springdoc.swagger-ui.layout=BaseLayout
springdoc.swagger-ui.tagsSorter =alpha
springdoc.swagger-ui.operationsSorter = alpha

Comment: Just a tiny comment, the BaseLayout alone seems to hide the whole top bar.